# app won't run on device & meta

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm searched both here and at apple's devforums and followed all suggestions and am still stuck.

Basically, my app runs in the Simulator but won't run when switched to the device (an iPod touch).  No errors - I get a 'finished running' message from Xcode.

The trick is that another of my apps does run on the device.  Hmm.

Incidentally (this is the 'meta' part) this bug is very confusing.  I haven't a clue where to look/what to read.  It makes me think that there's a document somewhere that I've missed.  Any ideas about solving these types of bugs in general?

Comment: Not with this little of information.

Comment: Speaking of a lack of information, instead of just downvoting and/or writing 6 words, maybe tell me what I should/could add?  I'm asking the question because I don't know what's going on.  in fact, I think that's part of what this site is about, no? Like I said, there are no errors or messages or anything.

Comment: In fact, this is probably technically the wrong place (meta.stackoverflow.com) but I honestly don't get the downvoting thing.  I can't fathom how it helps people get answers to questions (which is what this site is about, I'm assuming).  I'm going to upvote getting rid of them.

Comment: Has the device the right iOS version? What do you see on the screen of the device? Is it black or still spring board? IMPORTANT: What do you see in the console? One thing what could help: The simulator is case insensitive in respect of the resource names. The device not.

Comment: May be the IOS version of the device is greater or very lesser than the version you specified in the xcode targets. check the target requirements

Comment: Yes (on the iOS version), and it works with another app in the same version.  The screen is black - it just shows the top bar (with the time).  The console is just showing NSLogs - up to where the the persistent store coordinator (I'm using core data) is returned (apple's code) in AppDelegate.m

Comment: This information would have been useful in you question. (This is what I was talking about.) In addition show us the console output.

Comment: Of course it would have been useful but I didn't know to include it.  My apologies.

Comment: Now that that knowledge has been stewing in my mind a bit, I'm wondering if there isn't a problem with the storyboard file.  It's a guess, but AppDelegate.m seems to run on (as the console states) but the app doesn't progress past that..

Comment: So it seems to stop after didFinishLaunchingWithOptions runs in the AppDelegate.m which leads me to ask - how is the storyboard loaded? Maybe it's not getting triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holy camoley I figured it out.

I switched the following entry in the plist:

```
Main storyboard file base name (iPhone)
```

to this:

```
Main storyboard file base name
```

That did it.  I'm running on an iPod touch, but either way that seems like a bug as Xcode could just check that the plist entry matches the device being run on...